# RegEx Valip ZIP Code?

Tags: regex

i need a regEx in which 4 or 5 digits are okay (for german, austrian or switzerland ZIP).

Please help

Comment: Why not simply check the input length and make sure, it consists entirely of digits instead of using expensive regexes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^\d{4,5}$
```

However, this gives you no guarantee whether they really exist.

Answer (score 1):

A simple one would be (assuming Perl compatible regular expressions)

```
^(\d{4,5})$
```

You would still want to validate that it is an actual valid value afterwards (for example, you don't say whether leading zeroes are valid)

Answer (score 1):

This will match valid Swiss or German Postal Codes (Swiss are from 1000 - 9999, German from 00000 - 99999):

```
^(?:[1-9]\d{3}|\d{5})$
```

Comment: This will only match 5-digit codes starting with `0`. How about `^(?:[1-9]\d{3}|\d{5})$`? Uses a lot less parentheses, too.